# Angular update from Angular 2.2 to Angular 6.0

Tags: angular, webpack, updates

I have successfully updated Angular 2.2 to Angular 6.0 by following steps on https://update.angular.io/. The update was performed in incremental steps of 2.2->4.0->5.0->6.0.

In each update step I confirmed if >npm start gave the message of "webpack: Compiled successfully." and also checked if my application was accessible.

I am not sure if the update is 100% correct for the following reasons :-

1. I am still using webpack^1.13.0 and webpack-dev-server^1.14.1 which i am using to start the app as seen in the scripts of package.json. Is it fine for me to use the above? Note that i have tried updating to webpack^3.0.0. However, this resulted in some errors relating to webpack loaders. So, i reverted to webpack^1.13.0 and webpack-dev-server^1.14.1 and npm start seemed to work fine with the following webpack.config.js file contents:-
   module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev')

   Is it necessary for me to update webpack^3.0.0? If so, what should be my webpack.config.js?
2. I am not using ng serve or ng build although i have updated to angular-cli^6.0.0. Reason being, ng serve looks out for angular.json file which never showed up all along the update. Besides, the update did not mention how to generate one.

Following is my package.json, tsconfig.json and webpack.config.js :-

```js
{
  "name": "My APp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "AccessLint -2",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8088",
    "test": "karma start",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "build-css": "node-sass -w src/assets/sass -o src/assets/css",
    "watch-css": "nodemon -e scss -x \"npm run build-css\""
  },
  "license": "AccessLint",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-sass-loader": "^1.0.10",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "3.1.9-1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "font-awesome-webpack": "0.0.5-beta.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.1.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.9",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "font-awesome-loader": "1.0.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:-

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

web.config.js:-

```js
module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev')
```

typings.json :-

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "debug": "registry:npm/debug#2.0.0+20160723033700"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use angular CLI to build, you don't need to specify any webpack config, I would suggest trying to get the CLI build working. Bear in mind that `.angular.json` is a hidden file by default

Comment: I tried looking out for the angular.json not found error which came up when i ran   > ng serve or > ng build. Although  >ng new mynewApp generates the angular.json file, im not sure how to generate one for an updated project.

Comment: https://update.angular.io/

Comment: The update was performed following steps on update.angular.io

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file with name **angular.json** and add this file in your main directory. You might need to change your project name as angular doesn't allow spaces in project name.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "My-APp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/My-APp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "My-APp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "My-APp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "My-APp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "My-APp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "My-APp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "My-APp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "My-APp"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, Abdul. I am making the changes suggested by you and as of now stuck with "cannot read property 'sassloader' of undefined". It seems like i may have to touch base with the webpack.config.js file.

Comment: i think it has to do with the styles.css file. I am using bootstrap-sass-loader and fontawesome. Below is the vendor.ts file :- 
require('bootstrap-sass-loader');
require( 'font-awesome-loader');
import "bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js";
require("font-awesome-webpack");